# Equivalent of R's ifelse in Python

Tags: python, r, if-statement

I am ne w to Python so forgive me if this is a basic question. I am in the process of converting my R code into Python. I try to create new variable using data from other two variables. In R I would do the following:

```
df$new_col <- ifelse(is.na(df$col1) & is.na(df$col2), 99,
                ifelse(is.na(df$col1) & !is.na(df$col2), df$col2,
                      ifelse(is.na(df$col2) & !is.na(df$col1), df$col1,
                            ifelse(df$col2 > df$col1, df$col1,
                                  ifelse(df$col2 < df$col1, df$col2,
                                        ifelse(df$col1==df$col2, df$col2, "Error in coding"))))))
```

I have seen below bit of code in answers to the similar questions which works when I have only one condition but I can't get it work when it is more complex.

```
df['new_col'] = np.where(df['col1'].isnull() and df['col2'].isnull(), x, y)
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I think instead of the `and` you need to use a `&`

Comment: First or all, your original R code should probably be a `case_when`, not nested `ifelse` which are very unwieldy. Take a look at `np.select` for a Python alternative

Comment: For what it’s worth, this is not how I’d recommend writing this in R either. Check out the `match` function, it makes the code a lot more readable by allowing you to use vector lookup.

Comment: Just can't resist improving R code.... in R I think this can be simplified to `if (any(x == y, na.rm = TRUE) stop("coding error"); df$new_col = coalesce(pmin(df$col1, df$col2, na.rm = TRUE), 99)`

Comment: Thank you all for your useful comments. @GregorThomas Thanks for this bit of code. Forgive me my ignorance but I don't understand the first half. Would you be so kind and provide some explanation?

Comment: Your code has `ifelse(df$col1==df$col2, df$col2, "Error in coding")`, which I see as a problem because the result will be a number if everything is good (all your other results are numeric), but if there is a case where `col1 == col2`, then you return a string, messing up the data type of the result, making it non-numeric. I assume that if there is an error in coding, you want to do something about it, so instead of returning a string I use the `stop()` function which will make R stop and throw an error, alerting you to the problem. I take care of that contingency first, and then do the rest.

Comment: Though I suppose I used inconsistent names, so it won't work. A corrected version would be `if (any(df$col1 == df$col2, na.rm = TRUE) stop("coding error"); df$new_col = coalesce(pmin(df$col1, df$col2, na.rm = TRUE), 99)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a list comprehension with a function.

```
a = [np.nan,1,2,3]
b = [np.nan,-1,5,np.nan]

def build_list(a_i, b_i):
  
  if np.isnan(a_i) and np.isnan(b_i):
    return 99
  elif np.isnan(a_i) and ~np.isnan(b_i):
    return b_i
  elif ~np.isnan(a_i) and np.isnan(b_i):
    return a_i
  elif a_i > b_i:
    return a_i
  elif a_i < b_i:
    return b_i
  else:
    return "Error in coding"

[build_list(item[0], item[1]) for item in zip(a, b)]
```

```
[99, 1.0, 5.0, 3.0]
```

Here's how you would incorporate this into pandas (assign is doing the work of dplyr's mutate)

```
import pandas as pd

example_df = pd.DataFrame({'a':a, 'b':b})

example_df.assign(c = lambda df: [build_list(item[0], item[1]) for item in zip(df['a'], df['b'])] )
```

The resulting dataframe -

```
     a    b     c
0  NaN  NaN  99.0
1  1.0 -1.0   1.0
2  2.0  5.0   5.0
3  3.0  NaN   3.0
```